# Understanding Matlab multidimentionnal array

Tags: matlab

I would like to have a better comprehension of Matlab mutidimensionnal arrays and the `:` operator with a quick question

So I ran this example

```
A = zeros(2,3,4,5);
size(A)
% ans = 2 3 4 5

%% 1.
size(A(:,:,1,1))
% ans = 2 3

%% 2.
size(A(1,1,:,:))
% ans = 1 1 4 5

%% 3.
size(reshape(A(1,1,:,:), 4, 5))
% ans = 4 5
```

*1.* is the behavior I actually expected for all operations.

I don't understand why do I kept unwanted dimension in *2.*

Do I need to reshape like in *3.* everytime I need a subarray ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reshape` or simply [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) in this case.

MATLAB always removes trailing singleton dimensions (past the first two):

```
>> size(zeros(4,4,4,1,1))
ans =
   4 4 4
```

But it also adds them when needed (or as Ander points out in the comment, they are always implicitly there):

```
>> a = zeros(4,4);
>> a(2,2,1,1); % is OK
>> size(a,100)
ans = 
   1
```

On the other hand, other singleton dimensions are kept. `squeeze` removes them.

For your particular application it makes sense to remove singleton dimensions, but other applications would have problems if this were the default behavior. Imagine code that extracts a certain sub-volume, and changing the direction of the data depending on how many rows or columns are selected. For example:

```
>> a(1:x,1:y,1:z)
```

would return an array of size `(x,y,z)` as long as `x` and `y` are larger than one. Make `x=1`, and now it's an array of size `(y,z)`? Bad idea!

Comment: Extra info: technically the dimensions are there. `size(a,100)`

Answer (score 4):

Matlab removes singleton *trailing* dimensions only, so what you see is normal.

In *1*, you removed a 2D subset from a 4D array, but the first two dimensions were "row" and "column".

In *2*, the "row" and "column" are both singleton, and the rest of the array is in the third and fourth dimensions, so Matlab keeps it that way.

Instead of `reshape`ing, you can `squeeze(A(1,1,:,:))` to remove dimensions that have length one (except for dimensions 1 and 2, which are sort of hard-coded into Matlab).